# Native crash on Samsung

Tags: android, crash, native, samsung-mobile

I'm having a really hard time trying to fix a native bug that popup on our App. The stacktrace looks like this:

```
03-21 11:39:08.861 22893-23067/com.siplay.android_siplay A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 23067 (RxIoScheduler-2)
03-21 11:39:08.921 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-21 11:39:08.921 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j7elteub/j7elte:6.0.1/MMB29K/J700MUBS2BQB1:user/release-keys'
03-21 11:39:08.921 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
03-21 11:39:08.921 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
03-21 11:39:08.921 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG: pid: 22893, tid: 23067, name: RxIoScheduler-2  >>> com.siplay.android_siplay <<<
03-21 11:39:08.921 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
03-21 11:39:08.951 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'art/runtime/class_linker.cc:2253] Check failed: mirror::Class::kStatusNotReady == klass->GetStatus() (mirror::Class::kStatusNotReady=StatusNotReady, klass->GetStatus()=Class::Status[3604580]) '
03-21 11:39:08.951 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 00005a1b  r2 00000006  r3 de5f7978
03-21 11:39:08.951 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     r4 de5f7980  r5 de5f7930  r6 0000000b  r7 0000010c
03-21 11:39:08.951 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     r8 f47f3220  r9 f483ce44  sl daec479b  fp f4822fa8
03-21 11:39:08.951 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     ip 00000006  sp de5efd50  lr f6dca38d  pc f6dcc77c  cpsr 40070010
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0004277c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00040389  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0001caab  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00019d29  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0001756c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00330d43  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+210)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000f447b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+2226)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0011e3ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker10SetupClassERKNS_7DexFileERKNS1_8ClassDefENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEEPNS8_11ClassLoaderE+964)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00135873  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+186)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00135fad  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+732)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00136297  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE.part.589+522)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00136b5b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+50)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 0038e89f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache12ResolveClassEPKcPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderE+170)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0038e9e3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache4FromEPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEPKcb+306)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 0037b2f1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier26ResolveClassAndCheckAccessEj+432)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 0038144d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier25CodeFlowVerifyInstructionEPj+6160)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00383f2d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier20CodeFlowVerifyMethodEv+144)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 00384ee1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier14VerifyCodeFlowEv+868)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 00384ff5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier6VerifyEv+148)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 00386217  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier12VerifyMethodEPNS_6ThreadEjPKNS_7DexFileENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS7_INS8_11ClassLoaderEEEPKNS4_8ClassDefEPKNS4_8CodeItemEPNS_9ArtMethodEjbb+406)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 00386acd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFileENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS7_INS8_11ClassLoaderEEEPKNS4_8ClassDefEbPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSG_11char_traitsIcEENSG_9allocatorIcEEEE+1028)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 0038721f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror5ClassEbPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS7_11char_traitsIcEENS7_9allocatorIcEEEE+506)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 0013c563  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEE+666)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 0013cef1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker15InitializeClassEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEEbb.part.593+204)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #24 pc 0013dd7f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker17EnsureInitializedEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEEbb+94)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #25 pc 000c3687  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+38598)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #26 pc 001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #27 pc 00206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #28 pc 0020af5f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE4ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+538)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #29 pc 000c0695  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+26324)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #30 pc 001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #31 pc 00206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #32 pc 0020924b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE2ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+198)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #33 pc 000c0b41  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+27520)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #34 pc 001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #35 pc 00206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #36 pc 0020af5f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE4ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+538)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #37 pc 000c0695  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+26324)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #38 pc 001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #39 pc 00206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #40 pc 0020af5f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE4ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+538)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #41 pc 000c0695  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+26324)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #42 pc 001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #43 pc 00206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #44 pc 0020924b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE2ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+198)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #45 pc 000c0b41  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+27520)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #46 pc 001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #47 pc 00206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #48 pc 0020af5f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE4ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+538)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #49 pc 000c0695  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+26324)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #50 pc 001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #51 pc 00206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #52 pc 0020af5f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE4ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+538)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #53 pc 000c0695  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+26324)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #54 pc 001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #55 pc 00206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #56 pc 0020924b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE2ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+198)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #57 pc 000c0b41  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+27520)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #58 pc 001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #59 pc 00206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #60 pc 0020af5f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE4ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+538)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #61 pc 000c0695  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter15ExecuteGotoImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_+26324)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #62 pc 001ec6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge+136)
03-21 11:39:08.991 2177-2177/? A/DEBUG:     #63 pc 00206f05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
```

The bug seems to be happening by closing and opening the App several times. This is really weird because this bug popup from nowhere from one version to another, and the only thing that we added was some updates for the Android compat library. This bug seems to be happening mostly on Moto X Pure and Samsung devices.

This is the crash report that we are getting through Crashlytics NDK:

```
Crashed: .android_siplay|
0  libart.so                      0xf4686cfa art::mirror::Class::GetDescriptor(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)
1  libart.so                      0xf4686c0b art::mirror::Class::GetArrayDescriptor(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)
2  libart.so                      0xf4686d05 art::mirror::Class::GetDescriptor(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)
3  libart.so                      0xf47456b3 art::PrettyTypeOf(art::mirror::Object*)
4  libart.so                      0xf457578d (Missing)
5  libart.so                      0xf4575c3f (Missing)
6  libart.so                      0xf4576399 (Missing)
7  libart.so                      0xf4576be9 art::gc::collector::MarkSweep::ScanGrayObjects(bool, unsigned char)
8  libart.so                      0xf4576eff (Missing)
9  libart.so                      0xf4577071 art::gc::collector::MarkSweep::MarkingPhase()
10 libart.so                      0xf4577313 art::gc::collector::MarkSweep::RunPhases()
11 libart.so                      0xf456d2ad art::gc::collector::GarbageCollector::Run(art::gc::GcCause, bool)
12 libart.so                      0xf4591027 art::gc::Heap::CollectGarbageInternal(art::gc::collector::GcType, art::gc::GcCause, bool)
13 libart.so                      0xf4592621 (Missing)
14 libart.so                      0xf45ae095 art::gc::TaskProcessor::RunAllTasks(art::Thread*)
15 boot.oat                       0x73701377 (Missing)
```

Comment: Here's the full stacktrace https://gist.github.com/4gus71n/6cfbf5110b1627379b14b483ec9f9de0

Comment: did you manage to figure out anything about this one?

Comment: @poss Yeah, I never reply this question because I'm not really sure which is the cause. What I did was re-write the entire proguard file, check on by one the dependencies and adding/updating all proguard rules, that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that one

Comment: @poss did that worked for you?

Comment: @LucasS. No, It's been a long time since I worked on this project. WE never got to fix this issue. Gotta love those Samsung phones!